# Read Color from application resource

Tags: uwp, c++-cli, windows-10-universal

I need to get SolidColorBrush from the xaml below.

```
<Page
    x:Class="VGOUserInterface.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    MaxWidth="800" MaxHeight="480">
..
..
</Page>
```

How can i get the SolidColorBrush from the xaml above in c++/cxx?

I tried as below but it says 'Resources': is not a member of 'Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::Current'.

```
SolidColorBrush^ resourceStringMap = (SolidColorBrush^)Application::Current::Resources->Lookup("ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declared `SolidColorBrush` in the page resource, you need to get `SolidColorBrush` in the page code behind with following code, and  [`Application::Current::Resources`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.resources#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_Resources) was used to get resource in the App.xaml file.

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SolidColorBrush^ resourceStringMap = (SolidColorBrush^)this->Resources->Lookup("MyColor");
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" x:Key="MyColor"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```